# error TS2339: Property 'value' does not exist on type

Tags: angular, events

> error TS2339: Property 'value' does not exist on type

I got the above error while using the following codes

Code in HTML

```
<input type="text" (input)="title = $event.target.value" />
```

Can please anyone guide me also providing me with the solution?

Comment: If you want to achieve 2-way data binding use ```[(ngModel)]="title"``` instead of ```(input)``` event. Import ```FormsModule``` before.

Comment: Thanks Lukasz for your prompt response , as you know I m new so please can u guide me where to import that I mean in TS file where title variable is ?

Comment: You will import ```FormsModule``` in the module where your input component lives. [You can read more on this here](https://angular.io/guide/forms)

Comment: Again thanks I had import FormsModule Class in TS file where I had put some value into it 
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';

export class AppComponent implements OnInit{
  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.moviesInTheaters = [{
    title: 'The Great Qaid',
    releaseDate: new Date(),
    price: 190
  },

Comment: FormsModule should be imported in another Module-file  e.g ```AppModule```

Comment: Yes i did the same import in AppModule but still error remain same, also showing this error
error TS2531: Object is possibly 'null'

Comment: If you provide a Stakblitz with example I will look into this.

Answer (score 1):

As @LukaszGawrys already mentioned in the comment, you can use Angular two way data binding `[(ngModel)]` syntax as:

```html
    <input type="text" [(ngModel)]="title" name="title" />
```

For `ngModel` to work, you would need to import `FormsModule` as:

```ts
    @NgModule({
    declarations: [ ... ],
    imports: [
        ...
        FormsModule
    ]
    })
    export class AppModule { }
```

Comment: Many answers and explanations about TS2339 around - this is the one that reminded me: "Sure! The ngModel!"

Answer (score 0):

I think you can simply write it like this,

in your component make an event handler function like given below,

```
  onInput(e: any) {
    this.title = e.target.value;
  }
```

And your HTML file can look like this,

```
<input type="text" (input)="onInput($event)" />
```